# тупят стили css

Tags: html, css

Делал сайт, всё вроде бы было норм, и тут приехали - часть шапки не поакзывается, а именно часть с меню и посиком (При чём только на версиях для ПК/планшетов, на телефонах норм). Все части меню есть, клики по ним вполне работают, но сами элементы "Меню" и "Поиск" не отображаются. В чем может быть проблема?
ЗЫ: Не отображаются `<div class="menu">` и `<div class="find">` , весь код : https://codepen.io/ShevaR/pen/YzPEXNJ . Помещал CSS в HTML при помощи  потому что если его пихать в CSS отделение codepen'а, то его перекроет бутстрап, а это мне не особо надо..

PS: то есть, ни меню, ни поиска не видно и их нельзя выделить. Но через код элемента они отображаются, кликнуть на них можно (и будет совершено то или иное действие, то есть всё норм)

Comment: Не пробовал заглянуть в инструменты разработчика или там консоль?

Comment: Всё нормально, ошибок нет. Если стили поубирать, то все объекты видно, там со стилями трабблы. Только я вот найти так и не могу. Видимо, придётся шапку переделывать :с

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема здесь

```
*{
box-sizing: border-box;
z-index:-3;
}
```

уберите z-index:-3;
z-index - расположение элементов по оси z. то есть -3 , значит что все элементы спрятались. поставьте 1. и все вернется . в данном случае z-index не нужен вообще. применяется для абсолютно спозиционированных  элементов

Comment: спасибо вам) действительно, убрал z-index и всё заработало. ставил z-index я раньше, сейчас он тут и вправду не нужен..

Answer (score 0):

Ты криво задал класс .mobile_menu 
У тебя написано

`@media screen and (max-width: 738px)
.mobile_menu {
    display: block;
}`

а потом

`.mobile_menu {
    display: none;
}`

Не на кнопку смотреть надо, а на родителя кнопки. Отсюда и косяк

Comment: mobile_menu - скорее кривое название. это кнопка, которая появляется при переходе к разрешению 738px или меньше. типа кнопка, которая вызывает меню с мобильных устройств